# Jquery .each use. Queue?

Tags: jquery, html, queue, each

I have that code in jQuery:

```
function lshow() {
        var delayt = 500;
        var showtime = 5000;
        var ArrayOfElements = ['.slogan1','.whatwedo','.ekon','.ene', '.ekol', '.sm'];
        var i=0;

        $.each(ArrayOfElements,function (i,element) {
            if($(element).is(':visible')) {
                $(element).delay(delayt).hide('slow');
            }
            if ($(element).is(':hidden')) {
                $(element).delay(showtime).show('slow');
            }

        });
    }
```

and HTML:

```
<span class="slogan">
    <span class="slogan1">my slogan</span><!--Default visible-->
        <span class="whatwedo"><!--Default invisible-->
            projects <span class="sm">and modernization </span> of something <span class="ekon">fine</span>
        <span class="ene">fast</span>
        <span class="ekol">smooth</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.whatwedo, .sm, .ene, .ekol {
   display: none;
}
```

And I want to set it appear like that:

1. My slogan

*fadeOut*

1. projects of something fine

*"fine" fadeOut "fast" fadeIn*

1. projects of something fast

*same thing*

1. projects of something smoth
2. projects and modernization of something

But after 5 sec. it shows
"projects and modernization of something fine fast smoth"
and i cant get it working

Answer (score 5):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Kt38f/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var delayt = 500;
    var showtime = 5000;
    var ArrayOfElements = ['.slogan1','.whatwedo','.ekon','.ene', '.ekol', '.sm'];
    var i=0;

            $('.slogan1').fadeOut(delayt, function(){        
                $(".whatwedo").fadeIn(showtime , function(){
                    $('.ekon').fadeOut(showtime , function(){ 
                        $('.ene').fadeIn(showtime, function(){
                            $('.ene').fadeOut(showtime, function(){ 
                                $('.ekol').fadeIn(showtime, function(){ 
                                   $('.sm').fadeIn(showtime);
                                });
                            });   
                        });
                    });
                });
            });         
});
```

Comment: you could do it with `$.when()` and `.then()`, but you still end up with a lot of chained stuff...

Comment: Hmm not exactly. Span appear before the previous is hided so ther's a white space.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

Instead of putting the elements in an array, you put the *functions* that should be executed in an array and process it using `setTimeout`:

```
function lshow() {
    var intv = 5000;
    var funcs = [
        function() {
            $('.slogan1').hide('slow');
            $('.whatwedo').show('slow');
        },
        function() {
            $('.ekon').hide('slow');
            $('.ene').show('slow');
        },
        function() {
            $('.ene').hide('slow');
            $('.ekol').show('slow');
        },
        function() {
            $('.sm').show('slow');
        }
    ];
    var i = 0;

    setTimeout(function() {
        var func = funcs[i];
        if(func) {
            i++;
            func();
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, intv);
        }
    }, intv);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CcgpG/)

Answer (score 1):

I took a little bit of a different approach to it. Fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/SinS3i/xwc9a/1/

```
var currentStep = false;
var t = false;
ArrayOfElements = ['.slogan1','.whatwedo','.ekon','.ene', '.ekol', '.sm'];
var delayt = 500;
var showtime = 5000;
lshow = function(elements) {
    var lastStep = currentStep;
    currentStep = elements.shift();
    var hideIt = lastStep ? $(lastStep).has(currentStep).length === 0 : false;
    if(hideIt) {
        $(lastStep).fadeOut(showtime, function() {
            $(currentStep).fadeIn(showtime, function() {
                t = ArrayOfElements.length > 0 ? setTimeout("lshow(ArrayOfElements)", delayt) : false;                    
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(currentStep).fadeIn(showtime, function() {
            t = ArrayOfElements.length > 0 ? setTimeout("lshow(ArrayOfElements)", delayt) : false;
        });
    }
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    t = setTimeout("lshow(ArrayOfElements)", delayt);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Little bit edited ([http://jsfiddle.net/dVJvc/)](http://jsfiddle.net/dVJvc/):

EDIT: Sorry i didnt see yours responses. (THE CODE IS THAT SAME AS last ShankarSangoli)

Comment: Is this an answer or an addition to your question? If the latter, please edit your question instead.